# How can call razorpayX api using npm request?

Tags: node.js, request, payment, razorpay

Hello there I am working with razorpayX first time I need to create contact razorpayX API(s) using [npm request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) here is the [documentation](https://razorpay.com/docs/razorpayx/api/contacts/#create-a-contact) I tried my self but every time it's return "api key need for authentication" anyone can help me with this.

my code:

```
const result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const options = {
        method: "POST",
        "my_razorpay_app_key_id": "my_razorpay_secrate_key",
        url: "https://api.razorpay.com/v1/contacts",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        data: {
          "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
          "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
          "contact": "9123456789",
          "type": "employee",
          "reference_id": "Acme Contact ID 12345",
          "notes": {
            "notes_key_1": "Tea, Earl Grey, Hot",
            "notes_key_2": "Tea, Earl Grey… decaf."
          }
        },
      };

      request(options, async (error: any, response: any, body: any) => {
        if (response) {
          resolve({
            statusCode: response.statusCode,
            data: JSON.parse(response.body),
          });
        } else {
          reject(error);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking for solution or someone else is looking for the solution for the RazorPayX. I have recently created a sdk for `RazorPayX`, which supports most of the features of `RazorPayX`. This library can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/razorpayx-nodejs-sdk)

Regarding the actual question, you'll need to pass `Authorization` header in the request. Updating `options.headers` should do the trick for you.

```
options.headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": `Basic ${Buffer.from("apikey:apisecret").toString("base64")}`
},
```